# How to pass value to other page using Checkbox?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I want to pass the checked value I get from using Flatlist, ListItem from React Native Elements, and Checkbox. I have retrieve the value, but I don't know how to proceed after that.

```
const [extra, setExtra] = useState();
const [val, setVal] = useState('');

const onCheck = (item, index, event) => {

     let items = posts;
     items[index].checked = items[index].checked ? ! items[index].checked : true
     setExtra({posts:items})

     setVal(e.target.value)
     console.log(val) //returns undefined
}

return (
     <FlatList
         data={posts}
         keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'item'+index}
         renderItem={({item, index}) => (
             <ListItem>
                 <Text>Product Name>
                 ...

                 <CheckBox
                      checked={item.checked}
                      onPress={(e) => onCheck(item, index, event)}
                 />   
             </ListItem>
         )}    
         extraData={extra}       
      />
      <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={() => 
                props.navigation.navigate("Next", {items: items})} //not sure what to call instead of items, but I want to pass the selected value                      
      >
           <Text>SUBMIT</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

Can you please tell me what to do, and fix if I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please share the full component, for now you can do something like this :

```
const [extra, setExtra] = useState();
const [val, setVal] = useState('');

const onChange = (val, index) => {

     let items = [...posts];
     if (val) {
         const selectedItem = items[index];
         items[index].checked = val;
         setExtra({posts:items});

     setVal(e.target.value)
     console.log(val) //returns undefined
     }
}

return (
     <FlatList
         data={posts}
         keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'item'+index}
         renderItem={({item, index}) => (
             <ListItem>
                 <Text>Product Name>
                 ...

                 <CheckBox
                      checked={item.checked}
                      onChange={(val) => onChange(value, index)}
                 />   
             </ListItem>
         )}    
         extraData={extra}       
      />
      <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={() => 
                props.navigation.navigate("Next", {items: items})} //not sure what to call instead of items, but I want to pass the selected value                      
      >
           <Text>SUBMIT</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

Comment: May I know which part of component that you want to see, because my code is kinda long tho.